# No GCM notifications received in emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, google-cloud-messaging

I am developing an Android application that uses Google Cloud Messaging (GCM).
I follow these steps mentioned here: 
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

When running many emulators, Database can get registration ID for each emulator. But unfortunately, I cannot receive any notifications sent by my app server (local host).

Do you have any idea what would make this problem ?

That will be appreciated.

Comment: Which emulator are you using?

Comment: I am using Google APIs (Google Inc.).

Comment: How are you sending your messages? What are the GCM servers returning to you when you send your test messages?

Comment: Thanks a lot, I test it on a real device and it worked !